# Combine many images same filename from many differents folders in a batch process with python

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to combine all images one by one from 4 different folders, for example, I have those 4 folders:

- folder1: a_1.png, a_2.png, a_3.png
- folder2: a_1.png, a_3.png, a_5.png
- folder3: a_1.png, a_6.png, a_3.png
- folder4: a_2.png, a_6.png, a_5.png
  what I would like to do is combining:
- a_1.png in folder1 and a_1.png in folder2, a_1.png in folder3
- a_2.png in folder1 and a_2.png in folder4
- a_3.png in folder1 and a_3.png in folder2
  .....

I don't have any good ideas, plz help me to solve it

Comment: Combine many images same filename from many differents folders to 1 picture in a batch process with python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume by "combining two images", you mean concatenating them like stitching them into one

```py
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image

src_parent_dir = Path("parent/folder/of/folder1/2/3/and/4")
dest_dir = Path("folder/to/result/images")
img_name2path = {}  # look up buffer

for child in src_parent_dir.glob("*/*.png"):  # assume all images ends with png
    img_name = child.name
    src0_path = img_name2path.get(img_name)
    if src0_path is None:  # store first image, look for second image
        img_name2path[img_name] = child
    else:  # first image found
        src0 = Image.open(src0_path)
        src1 = Image.open(child)
        dst = Image.new("RGBA", (src0.width + src1.width,
                        max(src0.height, src1.height)))
        dst.paste(src0, (0, 0))
        dst.paste(src1, (src0.width, 0))
        # this puts them side by side horizontally
        '''
        dst = Image.new("RGBA", (max(src0.width, src1.width)
                        src0.height + src1.height)))
        dst.paste(src0, (0, 0))
        dst.paste(src1, (0, src0.height))
        # use this to stack them vertically instead
        '''
        name = src0_path.stem
        suffix0 = src0_path.parent.name  # used to make dest file name
        suffix1 = child.parent.name  # used to make dest file name
        dst.save(Path(dest_dir, f"{name}_{suffix0}_{suffix1}.png"))
        # result image is named like a_1_folder1_folder2.png
        img_name2path[child.name] = None  # reset buffer
# Finally, deal with leftover single images
for img_name, src_path in img_name2path.items():
    if src_path is None:  # no leftover
        continue
    src = Image.open(src_path)
    dst = Image.new("RGBA", (src.width, src.height))
    dst.paste(src, (0, 0))
    dst.save(Path(dest_dir, 
                  f"{src_path.stem}_{src_path.parent.name}.png"))
```

Comment: when i debug, it display: Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range
  File "D:\Desktop\testpython\learnPython\imagemagic.py", line 18, in <module>
    width, height = images[list(images.keys())[0]].size
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I assume you are commenting on another person's code? I don't see using symbols and methods as your error message says

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, but when i run your code , it don't display result, i don't know why, i change path of src_parent_dir and dest_dir

Comment: That's all you need to do. I tested the code on my machine and it works okay